# Moving a button into another class JPanel - Becker Robots

Tags: java, swing, button

I am using the Becker Robots making a board game with two player. One Random and one Human (me).

The player should click UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT buttons.

So far: I have created 2 classes. One that displays the board (9,9) and one that contains the player buttons.

I want to move this button into my main board display board. However, I want to keep these classes seperate because in order to make them do something I will need a listener class for each button which also redirects to the main.

```
import becker.robots.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PlayerButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        JPanel contents = new JPanel();


        JButton upButton = new JButton("UP");

        JTextArea textDisplay = new JTextArea (5,10);

        //set it up

        contents.add(upButton);
        contents.add(textDisplay);


        //display in panel

        frame.setContentPane(contents);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take a look to MODEL VIEW CONTROLER:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

It also could help if you post more code, but guessing, you could create a listener and check the boton id. On that way you'll be able to have just one listener.

Comment: Hi, I want to avoid using a mvc. 

I am planning on making a seperate listener class that does something when each of the button options are selected. For example: Some pseudo code:

If player clicks on button_UP, then the listener will check this action and make the players arrow move UP in the main class.

Comment: No code added, could you check it? Edit the first post

Comment: This is all I have so far. I am currently working on the listeners.